# a synchronized auto scroller using javascript, marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, marquee

I have an iframe in my website page which displays some small images and informations. I want to scroll the content inside iframe synchronizely,automatically upward when the page loads. I mean when the first line disappears , It should be shown down at the bottom of the iframe.

index.html contains

```
<iframe id='iframe_right' src="xyz.html" name='iframe_right' style="height: 300px; width: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

the xyz.html page contains a dividion containing images and informations which i want to scroll up ward.

```
<div style="height: 300px; >
line 1
line 2
line 3
.
.
.
.
line n
</div>
```

when the lines scroll upward, I want the line disappeared while moving upward should be shown at the bollom.
Like when line 1 moves upward and disappears then it should be shown at the bottom of iframe.
 when line 2 moves upward and disappears then it should be shown at the bottom of iframe bellow line 1 which is already at the bottom.
and so on .

I tried using the marquee tag in xyz.html by putting the div in side 
but it did not work as per my requirement

Thanks...